# Accessing pixel value with .at<uchar> and .at<Vec3b> does not work

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, pixel, grayscale

I am trying to rewrite the value for a pixel in a Mat-type grayscale image using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop. I've tried:

```
imgGrayComp.at<uchar>(5, 4) = 0;
```

.

```
imgGrayComp.ptr(4)[5] = 0;
```

.

```
imgGrayComp.at<Vec3b>(5, 4) = 0;
```

But it gives me this instead:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537
```

==========================================================================================

EDIT - Here's the code:

Calling classify():

```
classify("./src/0.jpg", contour, hierarchy, mDatabase, '0');
```

In classify():

```
void classify(std::string imageFile, 
    vector<vector<Point> > contour,
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy, float mDatabase [][charsToClassify],
    char whichChar)
{
    Mat image = imread(imageFile, 1);
    Mat imageGrayClassify;

    image.convertTo(imageGrayClassify, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    int numPoints = computeNumContourPts(imageGrayClassify); // calling compute...()
}
```

In compute...():

```
int computeNumContourPts(Mat imgGrayComp)
{

    // dilation x1 (increases workload):
    dilate(imgGrayComp, imgGrayComp, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 2);
    // erosion x1 (decreases workload):
    erode(imgGrayComp, imgGrayComp, Mat(), Point(-1,-1), 1);

    imgGrayComp.at<uchar>(5, 4) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more code. It seems to be a problem with imgGrayComp, maybe some size/type/depth-mismatch? Needs more information.

Comment: More code added. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that:

Instead of using `cv::cvtColor(image, imageGrayClassify, CV_BGR2GRAY);`, you used `image.convertTo()` which is meant to convert the datatype of the image.

In regard to the comment of a new error to Canberk's answer, it's simple, chances are your `image` is null/empty.

Use

```
CV_Assert(!image.empty()); //use this then the cvtColor, note this is a comment!!!

cvtColor(image,imageGrayClassify, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Alternatively, you can just use `imshow` to see if image is displayed successfully before even using cvtColor. Cheers.

Comment: This is it! ... Fixed. You were right. Turns out the paths to the files were wrong. I had to back up from the Debug folder into its parent folder and then into the "src" sibling folder. Now it appears that I've been dealing with two problems, and I don't know which one to mark as best.

Comment: @Andrey, I did answer both problems of yours the fastest, so I would ask you to give me the accepted answer. Haha. But of course, to avoid such dilemma next time, after a current problem is solved and a new problem appears, the usual steps taken by most is to accept the answer, and post another answer in regard to the new problem. You can comment the link of the new question to answered post to alert the person who answered so that he can get more reps if he solve the new problem(:

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of it. Once the first problem is solved, I mark that as best answer (even when I know of another problem in the same code), add a comment to that answer with a link to the answer for the second question ... that's where you've lost me. Walk me through step-by-step.

Comment: Haha. It's not a must. It's just what some user do, meaning, the second question,  u copy the link, for instance, the link of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234801/accessing-pixel-value-with-atuchar-and-atvec3b-does-not-work/22241061?noredirect=1#comment33779219_22241061, and share that link via comment of the post that the person who answered ur first question and say a new problem arised after following ur method, etc. Do take a look if u know how to solve it?

Comment: But different users, different mindset. Its just a suggestion as I seen people doing it. (;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `imageGrayClassify` is not a grayscale image of `image`. You use `.convertTo()` which can convert e. g. a `CV_32F`-image to a `CV_8U`-image but not BGR to Gray. This call will convert the image to `CV_64F` because `CV_BGR2GRAY == CV_64F == 6`. All just macros and a typeunsafe interface.

You need

```
cv::cvtColor(image, imageGrayClassify, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

then you shoud be able to access `imgGrayComp` with `.at<uchar>(5, 4)`. Be aware that `.at<Vec3b>(5, 4)` is still wrong, because a grayscale-image has only one channel. `Vec3b` is normally used for a 3-channel 8-bit image.

Comment: 1) Thank you for your input. 2) See my comment on Canberk's answer here.

Answer (score 1):

With the wrong call of convertTo, you are converting your image to 64F precision.

What you do here

```
image.convertTo(imageGrayClassify, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

is equivalent to

```
image.convertTo(imageGrayClassify, CV_64F);
```

since convertTo expects a data type enum; not a conversion enum. Your conversion enum (COLOR_BGR2GRAY = 6) is converted to data type enum (CV_64F = 6).

I suppose you meant to use [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) there.

And since your imageGrayComp is not grayscale nor 8U, you cannot access its pixels with vec3b or uchar.

Comment: I actually did try `cvtColor(image, imageGrayClassify, CV_BGR2GRAY );` , but the command prompt spat out `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737` . Also, according to the page you linked to, the first argument for cvtColor() has to be `constArr *` , not `Mat` .

Comment: ^ Sorry, I wrote `constArr *` ... I meant `const cvArr *` .

Comment: you are using c++ interface, and cvtColor accepts Mat data type. You can also use c interface and use IplImage* as your image data type, which is interited from cvArr*